# how to convert NSData to Binary data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need convert NSData to Binary data for send to php server

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to convert NSData. Just set the post body of the NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: I'm working with the Tumblr API and it states ```URL-encoded binary contents``` is required for video upload. Do you know how I can convert my NSData video object to a string of 0 and 1s?

Answer (score 1):

```
const void *p = [nsDataObject bytes];
NSUInteger length = [nsDataObject length];
```